# Wordpress excerpt on social sharing

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook

i have a problem with this post: http://www.clinicadelciclo.it/2017/02/23/biciclette-artigianali-di-qualita/

if i click on the facebook social button the article description is:

"the dandy horse, also called Draisienne or laufmaschine, was the first human means of transport to use only two wheels in tandem and was invented by the German"

Now seems tha wp excerpt working fine, checking the page code i've found this:

```
<div class="main-excerpt">
                    <p>Se vuoi una bicicletta originale, unica e inimitabile scegli tra le nostre biciclette artigianali firmate Scarponi®.</p>
                </div>
```

i checked also our feeds rss and wp excerpt seems correctly set up.

So why i get this text (that also i've found in their demo theme: http://demo.sunrisetheme.com/velo/a-brief-history-of-bicycling/

thank you in advance